# Block with 100% height on both viewport and page

Tags: html, css

That's the 10^6 $ question!

I've searched and read a lot about this, but is there a state-of-the-art method that would respond to the following problematic :

```
if height(block content) < height(viewport):
    height(block) = height(viewport)
else:
    height(block) = height(block content)
```

The bottom of the block should always touch the bottom of the page. I'm looking for the most simple, clean and cross-browser way to do this.

Thank you!

Comment: do you have a code exemple? a fiddle or something? i'm not sure I get what you're asking

Comment: Static or absolute positioning ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`min-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height) is what you're describing. Just know you'd have to give `html`, `body`, and all parent tags a height for percentage heights to work:

```
html, body, #someBlockId { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Note: I had to remove the margin and padding, because those are added *after* the height is calculated. [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) can change this behavior, but it isn't quite cross-browser.

Comment: Well i'm confused, it was quite simple! I was hesitating between several ways to do so! Here is a fiddle of the solution : http://jsfiddle.net/UYs3j/2/ thanks !

Comment: @XavierR. as Alex pointed out, as long as you don't have to support IE6, this one is pretty straightforward :)

Answer (score 2):

The most common way is to do this:

```
html, body { height:100%; }
```

Then set any elements which are to also fill the vertical space to height:100%.

Note: For this to work the item needs to be block-level and have content, even a &nsbp; would do and don't forget that padding adds to the height of the element so be sure to compensate accordingly if you absolutely have to have padding on that element.

Comment: SlightlyCubans method will also work quite well but it should be noted (just in case) that it will not work in IE6 without using a javascript function (known as a 'polyfill').

Comment: I thought `height: 100%` won't expand when content exceeds the viewport.

Comment: Yep. It will expand just fine provided that the content inside it is not floated (and even then it will expand if you properly clear the floats). If you don't require IE6 support though, min-height should serve you just fine.

Comment: My [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7VVKa/) seems to disagree. Content overflows using `height`.

Comment: It seems you are right! Odd that I've never come across that issue before myself. I've been using height:100% for years!

Answer (score 0):

Considering that :

> The bottom of the block should always touch the bottom of the page

I would go like :

```
.block {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Then set the height if `height(block content) > height(viewport)`.

If no `height` is set, it will take all the space of the offset parent.

If `height` is set, it will override `top:0; bottom:0;`.
Then if `height` is set and you remove `top` (remove, no set it to 0), it will stick to the bottom of the offset parent.

Comment: Do you see another way to set height dynamically without using javascript ?

Comment: Using `min-height` it works, but only if block is set to `top:0`, not `bottom:0` (see this fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/6CZzD/](http://jsfiddle.net/6CZzD/) and resize the result's height). Could use js just to toggle some classes. It would help if you showed the complete layout. Right now I don't know if absolute positioning really qualifies for what you want to achieve.